# Getting vendor and product IDs of a COMx port

Tags: winapi, serial-port, port

I know how to use CreateFile, etc... in C to communicate with a Arduino-type microcontroller, now I would like to know the vendor and product IDs of the device with its "COMx" port number. Is it possible ?
Optional: is it possible to get the name as listed in the Windows device manager with this "COMx" port number?
Thanks
David

I have been searching around the comm keywords to communicate with the device, but didn't find anything.

Comment: These articles will be helpful. [Windows Device Console (Devcon.exe)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon), [Windows-driver-samples/setup/devcon/](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/setup/devcon), [receive - serial port communication in c# codeproject](https://code-examples.net/en/q/2fb9b), [Identify COM port using VID and PID for USB device attached to x64](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10350340/9014308), [Identifying USB to serial port given USB VID and PID using WMI query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19899511/9014308)

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot, I'm on plain C, but searching through the registry gave me the answer.